# Object variable or With block variable not set but I can't find the issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in Excel VBA code, I tried to code to as below, but I always got the error (attached), Could you please help look what is wrong in my code?

Any help will be appriciated.

The code below

```
Sub test_row_count()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sodong As Integer
    sodong = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To sodong
        If cell(i, 2) = "123" Then
            cell(i, 3).Value = "Flag"
        Else
            cell(i, 3).Value = "NONE"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `cell` has been declared but not assigned. Trying to access it throws the error.

Comment: Which line of code is highlighted when the error is triggered?

Comment: You didn't define `cell` and probably meant to type `cells`

Comment: You never set `cell` to refer to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a variable `cell` but never set it to anything.

Later you tried to use that variable, while it was null.

```
Sub test_row_count()
    'Dim cell As Range    'Remove this line
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sodong As Integer
    sodong = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 1 To sodong
        If Cells(i, 2) = "123" Then
                Cells(i, 3).Value = "Flag"   'modify these lines
        Else
                Cells(i, 3).Value = "NONE"   'use Cells not cell
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```